# Batik rasterizer Blank png file

Tags: java, svg, png, batik

I'm using  batik-rasterizer-1.8.jar to generate png files. I got totally blank png output with the following svg file. I already tried different servers but it is the same result.

```
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" style="font-family:'lucida grande', 'lucida sans unicode', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600" height="380"><desc>Created with Highstock 2.1.5</desc><defs><linearGradient x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1" id="highcharts-31"><stop offset="0" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="1"></stop><stop offset="1" stop-color="#EEE" stop-opacity="1"></stop></linearGradient><linearGradient x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1" id="highcharts-32"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#8EB4E3" stop-opacity="1"></stop><stop offset="1" stop-color="#FFF" stop-opacity="1"></stop></linearGradient><clipPath id="highcharts-33"><rect x="0" y="0" width="496" height="300"></rect></clipPath><clipPath id="highcharts-35"><rect x="0" y="0" width="496" height="300"></rect></clipPath></defs><rect x="1" y="1" width="598" height="378" strokeWidth="2" fill="#FFF" stroke="#FFC000" stroke-width="2" class=" highcharts-background"></rect><rect x="20" y="20" width="496" height="300" fill="url(#highcharts-32)"></rect><image preserveAspectRatio="none" x="470" y="340" width="123" height="38" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://static.gurufocus.com/images/chart-exporting-logo.png"></image><text x="160" y="365"><tspan style="font-size:12px;fill:#000;font-weight:normal;">Interactive Charts. Apr. 21 2015, 14:25 UTC. Powered by </tspan></text><g class="highcharts-grid" ></g><g class="highcharts-grid" ><path fill="none" d="M 20 320.5 L 516 320.5" stroke="#558ED5" stroke-width="1"  opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" d="M 20 245.5 L 516 245.5" stroke="#558ED5" stroke-width="1"  opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" d="M 20 170.5 L 516 170.5" stroke="#558ED5" stroke-width="1"  opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" d="M 20 95.5 L 516 95.5" stroke="#558ED5" stroke-width="1"  opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" d="M 20 19.5 L 516 19.5" stroke="#558ED5" stroke-width="1"  opacity="1"></path></g><g class="highcharts-grid" ><path fill="none" d="M 20 320.5 L 516 320.5" stroke="#558ED5" stroke-width="1"  opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" d="M 20 245.5 L 516 245.5" stroke="#558ED5" stroke-width="1"  opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" d="M 20 170.5 L 516 170.5" stroke="#558ED5" stroke-width="1"  opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" d="M 20 95.5 L 516 95.5" stroke="#558ED5" stroke-width="1"  opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" d="M 20 19.5 L 516 19.5" stroke="#558ED5" stroke-width="1"  opacity="1"></path></g><rect x="19.5" y="19.5" width="497" height="301" strokeWidth="-1" stroke="#558ED5" stroke-width="1" fill="none" ></rect><g class="highcharts-axis" ><path fill="none" d="M -42854399732.5 320 L -42854399732.5 330" stroke="#558ED5" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" d="M 20 320.5 L 516 320.5" stroke="#558ED5" stroke-width="1"  visibility="visible"></path></g><g class="highcharts-axis" ></g><g class="highcharts-axis" ><path fill="none" d="M 556 320.5 L 566 320.5" stroke="#558ED5" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" d="M 556 245.5 L 566 245.5" stroke="#558ED5" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" d="M 556 170.5 L 566 170.5" stroke="#558ED5" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" d="M 556 95.5 L 566 95.5" stroke="#558ED5" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" d="M 556 19.5 L 566 19.5" stroke="#558ED5" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"></path><path fill="none" d="M 556.5 20 L 556.5 320" stroke="#558ED5" stroke-width="1"  visibility="visible"></path></g><g class="highcharts-series-group" ><g class="highcharts-series highcharts-tracker" visibility="visible"  transform="translate(20,20) scale(1 1)" style="" clip-path="url(#highcharts-33)"><rect x="129" y="132" width="239" height="169" fill="#0EB45A" rx="0" ry="0"></rect></g><g class="highcharts-markers" visibility="visible"  transform="translate(20,20) scale(1 1)" clip-path="none"></g><g class="highcharts-series" visibility="visible"  transform="translate(20,20) scale(1 1)" clip-path="url(#highcharts-35)"><path fill="none" d="M 238 300 L 258 300" stroke-linejoin="round" visibility="visible" stroke="#558ED5" stroke-width="23"  class=" highcharts-tracker" style=""></path></g><g class="highcharts-markers highcharts-tracker" visibility="visible"  transform="translate(20,20) scale(1 1)" style="" clip-path="none"><path fill="#708943" d="M 248 296 C 253.328 296 253.328 304 248 304 C 242.672 304 242.672 296 248 296 Z"></path></g></g><g class="highcharts-legend"  transform="translate(15,35)"><g ><g><g class="highcharts-legend-item"  transform="translate(8,3)"><text x="21" style="color:#333333;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;fill:#333333;" text-anchor="start"  y="15"><tspan>No. of Shares at Quarter Ends</tspan></text><rect x="0" y="4" width="16" height="12"  fill="#0EB45A"></rect></g><g class="highcharts-legend-item"  transform="translate(8,21)"><path fill="none" d="M 0 11 L 16 11" stroke="#708943" stroke-width="3"></path><path fill="#708943" d="M 8 7 C 13.328 7 13.328 15 8 15 C 2.6719999999999997 15 2.6719999999999997 7 8 7 Z"></path><text x="21" y="15" style="color:#333333;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;fill:#333333;" text-anchor="start" ><tspan>LVS Quarterly Average Price ($)</tspan></text></g></g></g></g><g class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-xaxis-labels" ><text x="-42854399730.745926" style="color:#000;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#000;width:380px;text-overflow:ellipsis;" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(0,0) rotate(-20 -42854399730.745926 338)" y="338" opacity="1"><tspan>2015Q1</tspan></text></g><g class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-yaxis-labels" ><text x="519" style="color:#000;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#000;width:1px;text-overflow:clip;" text-anchor="start" transform="translate(0,0)" y="324" opacity="1">55.74</text><text x="519" style="color:#000;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#000;width:1px;text-overflow:clip;" text-anchor="start" transform="translate(0,0)" y="249" opacity="1">56.74</text><text x="519" style="color:#000;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#000;width:1px;text-overflow:clip;" text-anchor="start" transform="translate(0,0)" y="174" opacity="1">57.74</text><text x="519" style="color:#000;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#000;width:1px;text-overflow:clip;" text-anchor="start" transform="translate(0,0)" y="99" opacity="1">58.74</text><text x="0" style="color:#000;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#000;width:1px;text-overflow:clip;" text-anchor="start" transform="translate(0,0)" y="-9999">59.74</text></g><g class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-yaxis-labels" ><text x="559" style="color:#000;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#000;width:1px;text-overflow:clip;" text-anchor="start" transform="translate(0,0)" y="324" opacity="1">0M</text><text x="559" style="color:#000;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#000;width:1px;text-overflow:clip;" text-anchor="start" transform="translate(0,0)" y="249" opacity="1">1M</text><text x="559" style="color:#000;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#000;width:1px;text-overflow:clip;" text-anchor="start" transform="translate(0,0)" y="174" opacity="1">2M</text><text x="559" style="color:#000;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#000;width:1px;text-overflow:clip;" text-anchor="start" transform="translate(0,0)" y="99" opacity="1">3M</text><text x="0" style="color:#000;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#000;width:1px;text-overflow:clip;" text-anchor="start" transform="translate(0,0)" y="-9999">4M</text></g><g class="highcharts-tooltip"  style="cursor:default;padding:0;white-space:nowrap;" transform="translate(0,-9999)"><path fill="none" d="M 3 0 L 13 0 C 16 0 16 0 16 3 L 16 13 C 16 16 16 16 13 16 L 3 16 C 0 16 0 16 0 13 L 0 3 C 0 0 0 0 3 0"  stroke="black" stroke-opacity="0.049999999999999996" stroke-width="5" transform="translate(1, 1)"></path><path fill="none" d="M 3 0 L 13 0 C 16 0 16 0 16 3 L 16 13 C 16 16 16 16 13 16 L 3 16 C 0 16 0 16 0 13 L 0 3 C 0 0 0 0 3 0"  stroke="black" stroke-opacity="0.09999999999999999" stroke-width="3" transform="translate(1, 1)"></path><path fill="none" d="M 3 0 L 13 0 C 16 0 16 0 16 3 L 16 13 C 16 16 16 16 13 16 L 3 16 C 0 16 0 16 0 13 L 0 3 C 0 0 0 0 3 0"  stroke="black" stroke-opacity="0.15" stroke-width="1" transform="translate(1, 1)"></path><path fill="url(#highcharts-31)" d="M 3 0 L 13 0 C 16 0 16 0 16 3 L 16 13 C 16 16 16 16 13 16 L 3 16 C 0 16 0 16 0 13 L 0 3 C 0 0 0 0 3 0"></path><text x="8"  style="font-size:12px;color:#333333;fill:#333333;" transform="translate(0,20)"></text></g><image preserveAspectRatio="none" x="556" y="134.25000000000003" width="48" height="32" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://static.gurufocus.com/images/arrow_chart_1.png" id="undefined_img" ></image><image preserveAspectRatio="none" x="516" y="303" width="38" height="32" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://static.gurufocus.com/images/arrow_chart_1.png" id="undefined_img" ></image><text x="561" y="154" id="undefined_text" ><tspan style="font-size:10px;font-weight:bold;fill:#0eb45a;">2250.0K</tspan></text><text x="521" y="323" id="undefined_text" ><tspan style="font-size:10px;font-weight:bold;fill:#708943;">55.7</tspan></text></svg>
```

I'm using the following command to generate png

```
C:\batik-1.8>java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar batik-rasterizer-1.8.jar -m imag
e/png -d test.png -w 600 chart.svg
```

There is a Exception in the output (invalid css value) but i'm sure it is not the reason of the blank png file. I can generate png files with other svg but only not this one.

The java version I already tried:

1.

```
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b25)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
```

2.

```
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.5.5.1.el6_6-x86_64 u79-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: What happens if you fix the CSS that Batik is complaining about?

Comment: It is the same problem. Blank png

Comment: Do any files work? If so compare them to the one that doesn't and change things one bit at a time to make the working one more and more like the one that doesn't work till you narrow down the issue.

Comment: Yes, i have other svg files works great with batik. But the content are totally different. I'll try your solution as a backup plan.

Comment: It doesn't render in batik-squiggle either. There are no errors reported. Clearly there must be something in the file that Batik doesn't like. It is going to require trial and error to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this element in the SVG file:

```
<path fill="none" d="M -42854399732.5 320 L -42854399732.5 330"
      stroke="#558ED5" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"></path>
```

If you remove it, the file renders fine.

I'm guessing the strangely large coordinate value is breaking Batik's number parser.

Comment: Reported to Apache Batik.  Although I am sure it is in all likelyhood, a known bug, I couldn't find it. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BATIK-1116